# How to check if user has access to digital product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here is the scenario:

A user buys a digital download. 
He pays for the download. 
(It is a wordpress plugin for info). 
He decides he wants a refund as not required. 
I refund, and remove the product from his account.

But...

As he has download he will continue to have use of the plugin.

So...

I would like to check that he still has access to the download via woocommerce and if not, "do something".

Problem...

I can't work out via woocommerce API how to check if a user has access to the digital download.

Any ideas, and thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm not using woocommerce but when user click on button for download file you can add on database id&product downloaded by the user. so if user has downloaded file, refund is not possible...

Comment: Thx for comment, however it's after download I'd like to check. If I've removed the download from their order, I want to automatically check. The other way could be to remove the order somehow and check, but struggling to understand woocommerce API.